# Vim: Why $ for end of line?

Tags: vim

I'm new to Vim and am curious as to why `$` would be used to go to the end of the line.  So, for example, `0` taking me to the beginning makes at least some sort of sense (first number on keyboard goes to first letter of line---understandable).

Is there any logic behind `$` or is it just totally arbitrary?

I was thinking `$`tart, until I remember it took me to the end!

Thanks!

Comment: For a better user experience, i prefer using this mapping `noremap H ^`
`noremap L $`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At some point it was arbitrary, but for decades `$` has been the symbol to indicate the end of a string in a regular expression.  `vim` is honoring historical precedent and making the keystroke very intuitive to people familiar with regular expression syntax.

Comment: It's possible that there was at some point, some layout, where `^` and `$` were next to each other, where it made sense, but it's pure speculation.

Comment: ``$`` is the classical symbol for indicating "end of input" in computing and language theory. [ASCII](http://www.december.com/html/spec/ascii.html) has an ``EOT`` (end-of-text) character, but it's non-printable.

Answer (score 2):

Dollar represents the end of line as it is used in Regex also. I think its arbitrary.

You can also use <kbd>A</kbd> to move to the end of the line and switch to editing mode

Answer (score 2):

if you know some regular expression, you would know that in regex, `$` means the the end of line. I **guess**, vi/vim took that idea.

Answer (score 0):

It may go back to the [use of `$` as a string terminator in CP/M](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.cpm/GrVgI0jk1HY%5B1-25-false%5D) (much like `\0` is the string terminator for C strings).

Why CP/M used it seems to remain a mystery.

Comment: I can't believe that vi (and therefore vim) copied *anything* from CP/M.

Comment: Probably not directly, but CP/M also seems to have borrowed it from some mainframe OS or other, so `$` for end-of-string seems to be a well established convention whose origins are a mystery.